# Generating python files with fixed code in them

Tags: python, python-3.x

in my everyday job I write different models and for each model I need to create a python file like this:

```py
class SomeModel:
    def define_params(self):
        return

    def define_input(self):
        return

    def run_model(self):
        return
```

I want to write a python script which will create a file with this format.

I tried:

```
import os

path = 'path_tol_folder_in_which_to_store_the_file'

if not os.path.exists(path):
os.makedirs(path)

with open(os.path.join(path, 'some_model.py'), 'w') as some_model:
some_model.writelines(
'class SomeModel:'
'    def define_params(csv):'
'        csv = ("PD", STRING)'
'        return csv'
)
```

When I run this code, the file is created but in there there is only one line:

`class SomeModel: def define_params(csv): csv = ("PD", STRING) return csv` (imagine this is one line)

and when I do ctrl+alt+L (format code) it does not format the code the way it should be.

Is there a way to do this so that the code format in the file is correct, i.e.

```py
class SomeModel:
    def define_params(csv):
        csv = ("PD", STRING)
        return csv
```

Thanks

Comment: just a thought. You could inherit from a parent class. The parent class has methods for parameter and states definition. In the child class you only define the run method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writelines` expects an iterable of strings (but will also accept a single string, as it does here), and what you passed is actually a single string: Python implicitely concatenates strings that are separated by whitespace (spaces, newlines...)

```
>>> 'abc'    'def'
'abcdef'
```

You could pass it a list of strings (note the `[]` and commas separating the strings), but you would have to explicitely include a newline `\n` at the end of each line:

```
some_model.writelines([
'class SomeModel:\n',
'    def define_params(csv):\n',
'        csv = ("PD", STRING)\n',
'        return csv'
])
```

or more simply, a multiline string:

```
some_model.write("""
class SomeModel:
    def define_params(csv):
        csv = ("PD", STRING)
        return csv
""")
```

Comment: `writelines` still requires newlines at the end of each line.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh, yes.. :/

Comment: Just slap `x + '\n' for x in` before your list

Comment: Yes... That is just so much easier to use triple quotes here...

Comment: The tripple quotes help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use triple quotes, which preserve blanks:

```
some_model.write(
'''class SomeModel:
    def define_params(csv):
        csv = ("PD", STRING)
        return csv
'''
)
```

Comment: `writelines` expects an iterable of strings ending in newlines. This magically works because strings are iterable, but you should really be calling `write` instead.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Right, it's copy-paste mistake :-)